# How to get the code coverage from sonar dashboard

Tags: sonarqube

Could someone help me to get the code coverage from sonar dashboard through curl REST API call? We are using the Sonar version as 6.7 and I am not able to find the REST call to fetch the same.

Comment: If it is available then it should be mentioned in the API documentation or do you have trouble executing the curl call?

Comment: @Jeroen Heier : I searched the latest docs and as per my analysis i dont see it. So just wondering if any of them tried and get it so far.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this :
 `curl "http://sq_instance:port/api/measures/component?metricKeys=coverage&componentKey=the_project_key"`

then you see :

```
{  
   "component":{  
      "id":"AWmbujtw_he9c8fQXlqh",
      "key":"blablabla",
      "name":"Sample Application",
      "qualifier":"TRK",
      "measures":[  
         {  
            "metric":"coverage",
            "value":"55.2",
            "bestValue":false
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

anyway you'll find all metrics keys here : https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.4/user-guide/metric-definitions/